# Why is the scheduled function never called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks

I have this very simple code to initiate a scheduled task in the background but nothing gets printed:

```
def printit():
    print("Hello, World!")


scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
scheduler.enter(2, 1, printit)
scheduler.run(blocking=False)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

It works if I set blocking to true. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't giving the scheduler back control to schedule events.  Try running at a later time.

```
def printit():
print("Hello, World!")

scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
scheduler.enter(2, 1, printit)

while True:
    time.sleep(1) # optional to prevent thrash
    scheduler.run(blocking=False)
```

Comment: You are right and your code works. But I expected the scheduler to run a background thread and execute the function when the time delay condition satisfies.

Comment: @suhas-k : To achieve what you described in comment, use threading.Timer(). It's simple and easy.

Comment: I have a more sophisticated requirement. I had tried using threading.Timer(). Rescheduling, among other things becomes difficult. I went with apscheduler - https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html